# Bitcoin exchange setup

Tags: exchanges, market, buttercoin

To whom may concern,

I am new to the scene of Bitcoin and have no prior computer/ technical background. I am planning to setup a personal exchange for trading rather than relying on exchanges and localbitcoin. Could anyone elucidate me as to how to setup a secure personal exchange and how to do backup just in case there is a computer virus or to prevent people from hacking. Please do not suggest Buttercoin as a platform as you need to pay them for each transaction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. The idea of a "personal exchange" doesn't make sense because to have an exchange, you need to involve other people (to trade with).

Comment: If you need to ask how, you shouldn't. Bitcoin and other crypto-currencies are extremely complex and delicate, you will only waste your own time.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin exchanges are complex networks designed to track bitcoin prices and to allow for secure buying and selling of bitcoins. This requires a vast programming knowledge in order to set up. Seeing that you do not have much of a technical background, I do not recommend venturing into setting an exchange up. That being said there are several exchanges that already exist, such as my favorite BTCe, that you may want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Check this opensource exchange for altcoins, with right hands you might contribute code for fiat:

https://github.com/r3wt/openex

Here is a bitcointalk thread: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=320975.0;all